# Is the S3 CopyObject operation strongly consistent?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've noticed that the `copyObject` operation in the Node.JS AWS SDK occasionally throws a `NoSuchKey` exception when I attempt to copy a file immediately after it's been created.

To try and counteract this, I've added a call to `getObject` - only attempting to copy if the file is actually returned by `getObject`. However this *still* occasionally results in `NoSuchKey` being thrown.

Is `CopyObject` exempt from the strong consistency model in S3?

Comment: I don't know, but it might be exempt, given it's not explicitly mentioned in this phrase: *"For all existing and new objects, and in all regions, all S3 GET, PUT, and LIST operations, as well as operations that change object tags, ACLs, or metadata, are now strongly consistent. What you write is what you will read, and the results of a LIST will be an accurate reflection of what’s in the bucket. For more details, read the documetation. "*, found on [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/consistency/). I'm slightly surprised, though. Only slightly ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-strong-read-after-write-consistency/, it really seems that list of actions supporting strong consistency is `GET`, `PUT` and `LIST`, while `COPY` not being listed.

That being said, I assume you could tweak your process to `GET` the newly created object, which is strongly consistent operation, and then `PUT` it to the new destination, thus not using the `COPY` operation.